# Search names by soundex() and partially names at the same time mysql

Tags: mysql

I have a database for movies where users search records by names. Sometimes the user misspells a movie name and I should get the record for him just like YouTube. At the same I should  get multiple records if the user writes a part of the movie name .

Examples, If the user is looking for the movie Saving private Ryan but wrote the name incorrectly Saving privat Ryan I should get the record for him. But if the user wrote private, in that case I should retrieve all records which have the word private.

I tried Soundex and it worked fine with the misspelled names

```
select * from movie where title soundex('Saving privat Ryan')
```

Partially names I used like

```
select * from movie where title like '%private%'
```

Is it possible to do the search in one sentence?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, just append the conditions with an OR:

```
select * from movie where title soundex('Saving privat Ryan') OR title like '%private%'
```

I would also suggest to use `Lower` function to make the query not case sensitive:

```
select * from movie where title soundex('Saving privat Ryan') OR lower(title) like lower('%private%')
```